# A Tree-based Map in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, return-value, binary-search-tree, key-value

mapSearch is a function that takes a key and a map, and returns the value associated with the key or None if the key is not there then return None.

**Question**: When I run the search function, it keeps returning the same value no matter what I put in for the key.

```
class EmptyMap():
    __slots__ = ()


class NonEmptyMap():
    __slots__ = ('left', 'key', 'value', 'right')

EMPTY_MAP = EmptyMap()

def mkEmptyMap():
    return EMPTY_MAP

def mkNonEmptyMap(b1, key, value, b2):
    node = NonEmptyMap()
    node.left = b1;
    node.key = key;
    node.value = value;
    node.right = b2;
    return node;

def mapInsert(key, value, mp):

if isinstance(mp, EmptyMap):
    return mkNonEmptyMap(mkEmptyMap(), key, value, mkEmptyMap())

else:
    if key == mp.key:
        mp.value = value
    elif mp.key < key:
        mp.left = mapInsert(key, value, mp.left)
    else:
        mp.right = mapInsert(key, value, mp.right)

    return mp

def search(key, mp):
    if isinstance(mp, EmptyMap):
        return None
    elif isinstance(mp, NonEmptyMap):
        if key == mp.key:
            return mp.value
        elif mp.key < key:
            mp.left = search(key, mp.left)
            return mp.value
        else:
            mp.right = search(key, mp.right)
            return mp.value
```

Comment: Could you show some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Start by fixing the obvious error in the last four lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue you're encountering is simply that you're not getting the return value you expect from `mapInsert`. The current code always returns the node that the provided value was inserted in, even if that is a leaf node somewhere deep in your tree. (And actually, not that I look closely at it there are some additional bugs with what you're recursing on and returning.)

I think you should change your `return` statements in the `else` block of `mapInsert` to return `mp`, rather than the result of the recursive call. The result of the call should be assigned to `mp.left` or `mp.right`, depending on which side we recursed on.

```
def mapInsert(key, value, mp):

    if isinstance(mp, EmptyMap):
        return mkNonEmptyMap(mkEmptyMap(), key, value, mkEmptyMap())

    else:
        if key == mp.key:
            mp.value = value
        elif mp.key < key:
            mp.left = mapInsert(key, value, mp.left) # don't return recursive result
        else:
            mp.right = mapInsert(key, value, mp.right) # pass the right child here!

        return mp # always return mp from this branch
```

Note that a more "Pythonic" design would probably use methods in a class, rather than a separate function to handle this kind of thing. This would require somewhat different handling of empty trees though.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious issue:

```
    if key == mp.key:
        mp.value = value
    elif mp.key > key:
        return mapInsert(key, value, mp.left)
    else:
        return mapInsert(key, value, mp.left)
```

One of these doesn't return anything at all, the other two return the same thing.